# Can't install apps via app center

Tags: appcenter

updated to Hera and consistently get this error code for every attempted install via app center.  What is the solution for this issue?

E: The repository 'http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter hera Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the sourcelist. Open the terminal and type;

```
sudo nano '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/appcenter.list'
```

replace all the **hera** with **bionic**

Save: [ctrl]+[o]
Exit: [ctrl]+[x]

Then

```
sudo apt update
```

You might as well check rest of your sourcelists;

```
sudo nano '/etc/apt/sources.list'
```